# delete popup working fine over project explorer view but not working over navigator view

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to hide 'delete' popup-menu for some files. I used following plugin.xml entry.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
<activity id="hidedeletepopupmenuID" name="hidedeletepopupmenu">
  <enabledWhen>
      <with variable="selection">
    <iterate operator="and">            
        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource" >
           <or>
            <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.java"/>
           </or>
            </adapt>
        </iterate>
      </with>
   </enabledWhen>
</activity>
  <activityPatternBinding activityId="hidedeletepopupmenuID"   
       isEqualityPattern="false" pattern="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete">
  </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>
```

This seems to be working fine over project explorer view, but navigator view its not wokring. Can anyone help on this?

Thanks,
darshan

Answer (score 0):

Actions in Navigator view context menu are hard-coded, see [ResourceNavigator.fillContextMenu(IMenuManager menu)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse.ui/ide/3.7.0/org/eclipse/ui/views/navigator/ResourceNavigator.java#ResourceNavigator.fillContextMenu%28org.eclipse.jface.action.IMenuManager%29).

Note that the action in popup menu is not the only way to delete a resource (there's also a menu item in Edit menu and key-binding).